# Listado de events?

Tags: jquery

he empezado a programar recientemente y estoy utilizando jquery, he visto un par de posts sobre como conseguir las coordenadas del ratón usando el siguiente codigo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").mousemove(function(event){
        var mouseX = event.pageX;
        var mouseY = event.pageY;
        $("#x").text(mouseX);
        $("#y").text(mouseY);
    })
})
```

Lo que necesito es las coordenadas del ratón del cliente no las de la pagina.
Aqui mis dos dudas:
¿Hay alguna pagina para ver todos los "event.???" ?
¿Podria alguien decirme si es posible conseguir las coordenadas del raton del cliente?
Gracias!

Comment: Este código es leído del lado del cliente y por ende esas coordenadas serían recuperables, puedes explicarte mejor?

Comment: Claro, las coordenadas que me da el event.pageY son las de la pagina, necesito las coordenadas de donde esta el ratón independientemente del scroll. Por ejemplo que la Y sea 0 si esta el ratón arriba del todo aunque en el scroll estés abajo del todo de la pagina web.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor visita el [tour] y revisa [ask]. Es importante que sepas como funcionamos y qué necesita una pregunta para recibir respuestas satisfactorias. Para el caso particular de los eventos del mouse revisa [MouseEvents](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/)